# requests_HTML pagination: list could not be stored

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests-html

I tried to store various pages as list by using request_HTML. whereas unable to store entire pages, could you help to store as list of page links...

may i know where am missing?.  May i know how to create a pagination like scrapy?

```
        from requests_html import HTMLSession

        def pagecheck(checkl):
            x=se.get(checkl)
            if x.html.find('div.isaiminida'):
                print (''.join(x.html.find('a.pagination_next',first=True).absolute_links))
                xplink= (''.join(x.html.find('a.pagination_next',first=True).absolute_links))
                if x.html.find('a.pagination_next'):
                    pages.append(xplink);return p(xplink)
            else:
                print ('Page doesnt exist')

        def p(xplink):
            x=se.get(xplink)
            if x.html.find('a.pagination_next'):
                pagecheck(x.url)
            else:
                print (z,'\t Pages scrape completed.....')
            return pages
            
            
        if __name__ == '__main__':

            #:: movies index
            xa = ['a','z','c']
            for z in xa:

                url = f'https://isaidubb.co/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/{z}'
                se = HTMLSession()
                x=se.get(url)
                pages =[];px=[]
                pages=pagecheck(x.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

when adding append and extend in main functions , i can able to list/stored all pages.

this code would be suitable who using listing all pages for scraping .....

```
            from requests_html import HTMLSession

            '''
            request HTML; pagination implementation

            '''

            def pagecheck(checkl):
                x=se.get(checkl)
                if x.url not in px:
                    px.append(x.url)
            
                if x.html.find('div.isaiminida'):
                    xplink= (''.join(x.html.find('a.pagination_next',first=True).absolute_links))
                    if xplink not in px:
                            px.append(xplink)
                    if x.html.find('a.pagination_next'):
                    return p(xplink)
                else:
                    print (z,'\t Page doesnt exist')

            def p(xplink):
                x=se.get(xplink)
                if x.html.find('a.pagination_next'):
                    pagecheck(x.url)
                else:
                    print (z,'\t Pages scrape completed.....')
                return px
                
                
            if __name__ == '__main__':

                #:: movies index
                xa = ['a','z','c']
                pz = []
                for z in xa:

                    url = f'https://isaidubb.co/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/{z}'
                    se = HTMLSession()
                    x=se.get(url)
                    px=[];pagecheck(x.url)
                    if px not in pz:
                        pz.extend(px)

                print (pz)
```

output will be:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\karthik\lala\FilesDump\movies\pageV1.py"
a    Pages scrape completed.....
z    Page doesnt exist
c    Pages scrape completed.....
['http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/a', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/a/2', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/a/3', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/a/4', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/z', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/c', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/c/2', 'http://isaidub7.com/tamil-atoz-dubbed-movies/c/3']

[Done]